# Content Security Policy nuxtjs embedding youtube videos

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, content-security-policy, nuxtjs

I am totally new to javascript development and I am hitting a brick wall.

In my nuxtjs app I want to embed plyr (vue-plyr module) and some youtube videos.

Locally everything works flawlessly, but once I put the site online. Videos are not loading and plyr is also not loading.

So I have come to the issue of Content Security Policy.  I have tried several things but none work.

Here is my latest attempt to get it to work:

```
  render: {
    csp: {
      reportOnly: true,
      hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
      policies: {
        'default-src': ["'self'" ],
        'img-src': ['https:', 'http:',],
        'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        'script-src': [
          "'self'",
          "'unsafe-inline'",
          '*.youtube.com',
          '*.ytimg.com',
          '*.plyr.io',
        ],
        // 'connect-src': ['*.youtube.com', '*.ytimg.com'],  
      },
      // addMeta: true
    }
  },
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CSP with `reportOnly: true,` blocks nothing, only sends reports. Therefore it should not affect Plyr player at all.
   You may be edit a file that is not actually being used to publish the CSP. Quite possible, really CSP is published by [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) middleware.
    It need to see the CSP violation message from the browser console to understand what's going on.
2. Content Security Policy to play [youtube video via Plyr](https://csplite.com/csp/svc150/#CSP_rules) player a little bit more complicated than you shown.

Comment: I see in the Dev Tool that HTTP header `content-security-policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` is published. I guess it's because Node.JS server have Helmet middleware installed. Check the `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` settings

Comment: ok mhh all I have here is nuxtjs published via pm2 on nodejs. no express app or anything behind it. Is helmet built in at standard nodejs implementation?

Comment: I found it. Oh my effin word! it was one line in my nginx config! Thanks a bunch for pointing in the right direction!